# How do i sort this ArrayList by the second object, in this case "cost"?

Tags: java, arraylist

Here are the parameters:

```
public class SoftwareProject implements Comparable<SoftwareProject> {
    String porjectID;
    double cost;
    int duration;

    public SoftwareProject(String id, double cost, int duration)
    {
        this.porjectID = id;
        this.cost = cost;
        this.duration = duration;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(SoftwareProject rhs) {
        return Double.valueOf(this.cost).compareTo(cost);
    }
}
```

Here is the main file:

```
public class CaluclateArray {

    static List<SoftwareProject> list;

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        initialize();

        int sum = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            sum += list.get(i).cost;

            System.out.println("Sum: " + sum + "\n");
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
        {
            System.out.println(list.get(i).cost);
        }


        //System.out.println("Prices of top 5 most expensive: " + list.get(0).cost);
    }

    static void initialize() {
        list = new ArrayList<>();
        SoftwareProject s = new SoftwareProject("5434", 225000.0, 152);
        list.add(s);
        s = new SoftwareProject("1234", 50000.0, 52);
        list.add(s);
        s = new SoftwareProject("2234", 1000.0, 35);
        list.add(s);
        s = new SoftwareProject("2134", 10000.0, 35);
        list.add(s);
        s = new SoftwareProject("2224", 1110000.0, 35);
        list.add(s);
        s = new SoftwareProject("2244", 140000.0, 35);
        list.add(s);
        s = new SoftwareProject("2235", 30000.0, 35);
        list.add(s);
        s = new SoftwareProject("2236", 750000.0, 35);
        list.add(s);
        s = new SoftwareProject("2237", 75000.0, 35);
        list.add(s);
        s = new SoftwareProject("2254", 8000.0, 35);
        list.add(s);
        s = new SoftwareProject("2634", 80000.0, 35);
        list.add(s);
        s = new SoftwareProject("2231", 23000.0, 35);
        list.add(s);
        s = new SoftwareProject("4321", 15000.0, 35);
        list.add(s);

        Collections.sort(list);
    }
}
```

I am wondering how to make it sort by the second parameter (`cost`) in the constructor `SoftwareProject(String id, double cost, int duration)`, I am having difficulties doing this.

`Collections.sort(list);` isn't working

Comment: Your `compareTo` is wrong. You are not using the 2nd object (`rhs`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is occurring in your compareTo method. By comparing this.cost with cost, you're essentially comparing a single object's cost with itself because `this.cost` is the same as `cost`. `cost` is just a field in the SoftwareProject class, but you need to access two different cost fields and what you currently have only accesses one`this` cost field, which is that of  The simple solution is to use the parameter in your method.

```
@Override
    public int compareTo(SoftwareProject rhs) {
        return Double.valueOf(this.cost).compareTo(rhs.cost);//you can even switch
                                                             //this.cost with rhs.cost
                                                             //or even write cost instead of this.cost
    }
```

Comment: I wanted to say thanks! This works! Can't believe that's all it was! I've never gotten the hang of Java, always baffles my mind how simple something is but how difficult it can be to figure out (as a newbie here).

Thanks again!